# How to render the first tab link component of a child component in react nested routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, react-router-dom, web-frontend

I'm very much new to react and i'm testing a tabs layout here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/lpjlqo7n4z  where i have 2 navigations, a **Home** and **About** which renders different contents. Inside the Homepage there's 2 more inner navigation links with different routes. Now my question is how to automatically render the component of the first tablink inside the homepage just below the inner navigation?

**Assuming everything is imported properly, here's my Index.js code:**

```
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <div className="logo">
          <figure>
            <p>Logo</p>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <nav>
         <ul>
           <li>
             <Link to="/" exact>Home</Link>
           </li>
           <li>
             <Link to="/about" exact>About</Link>
           </li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Home {...props}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/about" render={props => <About {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

**Home component:**

```
const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <div className="page-header">
        <h1>Homepage</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="page-nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to={`/graphics-design`}>Graphics Design</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={`/development`}>Development</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="page-content">
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${match}/:topicId`} render={props => <DesignTab />} />
          <Route
            path={`${match}/:topicId`}
            render={props => <DevelopmentTab />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**And the first tab component:**

```
const DesignTab = props => {
  return (
    <div className="tab-content">
      <div className="tab-header">
        <h1>Design Works</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="tab-details">
        <p>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur
            dignissimos corrupti eius vero maxime architecto similique odio
            maiores nihil accusantium iure error et voluptate placeat excepturi
            blanditiis, ad numquam itaque.
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DesignTab;
```

**How do i automatically render the tab content just below the inner navigation of the homepage?**

Please see the layout here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lpjlqo7n4z

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your program you need to address before starting your problem:

The tab content just below the inner navigation of the homepage is impossible to render because the path is impossible to reach. You basically saying "Once im in the `/` home path, i want to match `/gaming/:topicId` paths" but this isn't possible because the only way to get to your Home component is to `exact`ly match `/` in your index. So you can't exactly match `/` as well as `/gaming/topicId`.

I would recommend moving these routes to your `index.js` file:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`${match}/:topicId`} render={props => <DesignTab />} />
  <Route
    path={`${match}/:topicId`}
    render={props => <DevelopmentTab />}
  />
</Switch>
```

I don't understand what you want this Route to match to because the `match` object doesn't make sense in this context.

When you make statements like `render={props => <Home />`, the props are not being sent to your Home component. You must tell the component you want to send it props via `render={props => <Home {...props} />` instead.

Also `const Home = (props, { match })` is not the correct syntax and match will always be undefined here. Change to `const Home = (props)` then you can access match via `props.match`.

I hope my advice helps :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, yes i didn't included the props in the home and about component, that's typo but what i want to achieve is, the Home component should have 2 tab links that is already rendering the first tab component. If you check the link i provided: https://codesandbox.io/s/lpjlqo7n4z , i manage to render it all except for the tab component below the tablink is not showing.